# Dividir em partes iguais c#

Tags: c#

Tenho uma classe chamada cliente, uma chamada retornos, e outra chamada técnicos.

em um certo periodo do mes, eu crio os retornos para esses clientes.

depois de criar os retornos, eu quero dividir para os técnicos que eu selecionar.

por exemplo. eu tenho 100 clientes, então vou gerar 100 retornos.
dai eu vou la e seleciono 4 técnicos.

na minha controller, estou recebendo um array de técnicos `int[] IdTecnico`

então vou no banco e busco os retornos gerados

```
var retorno = db.retornoDb.Tolist()
```

como eu faço para fazer a distribuição?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você quer dividir um vetor *X* para *Xn* itens, e armazenar num vetor onde *t = Xn / l(t)*, assumindo que *l* seja a contagem de itens em *t*, e então você pode percorrer pelos mesmos e modulando seu índice por cada um:

```
    int[] x = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}; // <~~~ var retorno = db.retornoDb.Tolist()
    int[] t = new int[] {500, 501, 502, 503};   // <~~~ int[] IdTecnico
    int xn = t.Length;

    Dictionary<int, List<int>> tecnicosDivididos = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

    // inicializa os itens no dicionario
    foreach(int T in t) {
        tecnicosDivididos.Add(T, new List<int>());
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++) {
        int I = i % xn;
        int name = t[I];
        (tecnicosDivididos[name] as List<int>).Add(x[i]);
    }

    foreach(KeyValuePair<int, List<int>> item in tecnicosDivididos) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} => {1}", item.Key, string.Join(", ", item.Value));
    }
```

<sub>Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Snyw3P).</sub>

Desta forma, *Xn* sempre será a contagem de técnicos presentes em *t*. Os valores são armazenados num dicionário de `string, List<int>`, mas no seu caso, você pode passar para `Tecnicos, List<retorno>`. Você apenas precisará informar uma forma de encontrar os técnicos por uma chave, seja pelo nome ou por uma outra variável única por item (no seu caso você usa o ID, e implementei no exemplo o uso do ID).

Provavelmente você deverá alterar o tipo de `x` por ele ser um `int[]` e passar a ser um `retorno[]`, mas isso não é necessário se você iterar os índices destes retornos. Para gerar esse vetor de índices, poderia usar o [`Enumerable.Range(0, retorno.Length)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range), e depois, associar cada índice a cada item no `retorno[]`.

Aconselho fazer isso e depois passar a notação para `Tecnicos`, assim, não irá quebrar o algoritmo. Se procurar chave pelo tipo `Tecnicos`, a referência irá fazer com que a chave não exista, e brevemente não terá o resultado esperado.

> Observação: a enumeração de retornos por técnico não é diretamente sequencial, e sim modular. De fato, não haverá itens repetidos por técnico, e a divisão será igual se ambos forem pares. Se a contagem de itens em *X* for impar, um técnico ficará com um item a mais. Se a contagem de itens em *T* for impar, um técnico ficará com um item a menos.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode criar um método genérico de distribuição:

```
public static class Extensoes {
    public static Dictionary<TU, List<T>> Distribuir<T, TU>
        (this IEnumerable<TU> membros, IEnumerable<T> itens)
    {
        // Dada uma lista de itens a serem distribuídos a uma lista de membros,
        var eItens = itens.ToList();
        var eMembros = membros.ToList();

        // Inicializando o mapa a ser retornado: 
        // Uma coleção vazia de Itens para cada Membro.
        var mapaDeDistribuicao = eMembros
            .ToDictionary(i => i, i => new List<T>());

        // Cache estático do número total de membros
        var numeroDeMembros = eMembros.Count;

        var indiceDeContainer = 0;

        foreach (var item in eItens) // Para cada item da lista de Itens,
        {
            // Adicione-o ao container(Membro) atual;
            mapaDeDistribuicao[eMembros[indiceDeContainer]].Add(item);

            // Selecione o próximo container, ou o primeiro se chegamos ao último.
            indiceDeContainer = (indiceDeContainer + 1) % numeroDeMembros;
        }

        return mapaDeDistribuicao;
    }
}
```

Assim você poderá gerar mapas de distribuição de valores. No exemplo abaixo,

```
    var clientes = new List<string>
    {
        "Cliente 1",
        "Cliente 2",
        "Cliente 3",
        "Cliente 4",
        "Cliente 5",
        "Cliente 6",
        "Cliente 7",
        "Cliente 8",
        "Cliente 9",
        "Cliente 10",
        "Cliente 11",
        "Cliente 12",
        "Cliente 13"
    };

    var Tecnicos = new List<string>
    {
        "Tecnico 1",
        "Tecnico 2",
        "Tecnico 3"
    };

    var distribuicao = Tecnicos.Distribuir(clientes);
```

O dicionário `distribuicao` conterá uma lista de clientes para cada Técnico:

```
Tecnico 1
    Cliente 1
    Cliente 4
    Cliente 7
    Cliente 10
    Cliente 13

Tecnico 2
    Cliente 2
    Cliente 5
    Cliente 8
    Cliente 11

Tecnico 3
    Cliente 3
    Cliente 6
    Cliente 9
    Cliente 12
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0bxGBF)